# Add/Remove items from one set to form a subset

Tags: user-interface, widget

What is it called when you have a box with all of the elements from a set and you have buttons to add/remove those items to form a subset of those items?

```
Apples                               Cherries
Oranges        Add->                 Watermellon
Grapes         <-Remove
Pears
Kiwi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be 'Item Selector'?